# Laravel - SQLSTATE[HY001] Unable to allocate sufficient memory - MsSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, tinker

I'm making a second connection of my project in laravel with a view in an MsSql database, I configured my .env and config correctly, however this is an error of memory overflow:

```
$ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.10.5 (PHP 7.3.24-3+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> use App\Condinvest\BoletoPropCondominio as BPC
>>> BPC::first();
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY001] Unable to allocate sufficient memory (meudominio.com.br:5000) (severity 8) (SQL: select top 1 * from [View_Boleto_Prop_Condominio])'
>>>
```

already changed in my php.ini:

```
memory_limit = 128M
```

but the error continues.

My models briefly look like this:

BaseView.php

```
<?php
    
namespace App\Condinvest;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BaseView extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'condinvest';
}
```

BoletoPropCondominio.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Condinvest;

class BoletoPropCondominio extends BaseView
{
    protected $table = 'View_Boleto_Prop_Condominio';

    protected $fillable = [
        'Id_Condo_lan',
        ...
        'Id_titular'
    ];
}
```

when I do the same query directly through the command terminal:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM View_Boleto_Prop_Condominio;
```

returns my data successfully.

Can anyone tell me what may be happening, or how I can debug better to understand where the error is, please.

**EDIT**

```
>>> DB::connection('condinvest')->getConfig()['driver']
=> "sqlsrv"
```

Comment: How much did you increase `memory_limit ` to?

Comment: I put memory_limit =  -1

Comment: When I had an issue with the memory, setting it to -1 did not resolve it even though I was expecting it to. I then tried something like 2G and the error cleared up. I wasn't trying to use the package you are but figured I'd at least share my experience with this error from a month ago.

Comment: Not solve, I tried to restart with "apache2ctl restart" was not too, is there any chance of the error being on the server side of the database?

Comment: @MarciusLeandro Never set the memory limit to -1, that means there is no limit anymore. I think it is not the php memory limit, because that would throw a php error and not an sql error. Anyway, the solution should not be increasing the memory limit, but decreasing the memory usage.

Comment: what is your mssql version?

Comment: @bhucho I don't know, the database is from a third party, and I only have access to the route of a view

Comment: The error is returned from the database itself. It appears to be some memory issue, so please share the specs and which services you're running inside the same environment.

Comment: Are other queries working?

Comment: straight through the terminal yes, through the tinker none

Comment: @MarciusLeandro , it sounds that the issue exists in either DB configuration or tinker if you have no problem to connect mssql DB from Laravel. Please check allocated memory in DB just in case. please refer to [check mssql server memory](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4182/setting-a-fixed-amount-of-memory-for-sql-server/). If enough memory is allocated to mssql, tinker might have compatibility issue with mssql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the error is apparently being reported by the database process (not the php process), I would **not** expect changes to memory limits in php.ini to have any effect.

I found [this issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/25133) which mentions this specific error when using a deprecated driver with MSSQL Server.
To check which driver Laravel is using, type `DB::connection()->getConfig()['driver']` into your Tinker console. If you see `sqlsrv` then everything is ok here, but if you see `dblib` then this might be the source of the error. This problem was supposedly [fixed](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/25150) in Laravel 5.7 to prefer the supported drivers if more than one is available, but it's also possible that your `database.php` config file uses the wrong one.

It is also possible that the memory limits of the database server or the system it resides on are actually being exceeded. Being able to run the query in a command prompt without getting the error suggests that this is *not* the case, but it may still be worth investigating. If the available memory is very low then it's possible that there is not enough to run both php and the database query at the same time. You can check the available system memory by running the `free -h` command in the terminal, as long as the database process is running on the same machine as your terminal. However, if you are using a shared hosting provider then it is possible that the database is on a separate machine.

Comment: I saw in several places talking could be this, but I fixed it on the drive, and the error still persists

Comment: @MarciusLeandro what version of Laravel are you running (`php artisan --version`)? Also,  what were the results for checking the free system memory, and what was the database driver being used by the `DB` connection?

Answer (score -1):

If it helps, i encoutered the same issue. What i did in order to fix it was to check my configuration in database.php, if you use sqlserver, make sure you have charset set to utf8 as follows. It was previously set to utf8mb4.

```
'sqlserver' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_SQL_HOST'),
        'port' => env('DB_SQL_PORT'),
        'database' => env('DB_SQL_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_SQL_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_SQL_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'options' => [
            PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 300
        ]
    ]
```

Comment: Do not use utf8, it does not allow full use of Unicode.