# SQLSTATE[HY001] Unable to allocate sufficient memory - Laravel 8

Tags: sql-server, laravel

I have the following problem when trying to connect to a database in sqlserver that is on a shared server from laravel.

**Problem:**

[image: Query error from postman.]

I am using laravel 8. I would be very grateful if anyone has solved this problem or something similar has happened and can help me.

Note: I have reviewed several forums and tested the sqlsrv driver is correct with tinker.

Review and verify what they tell me in this other stackoverflow link but it does not work for me.

[Laravel - SQLSTATE[HY001] Unable to allocate sufficient memory - MsSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65395463/laravel-sqlstatehy001-unable-to-allocate-sufficient-memory-mssql)

Comment: Your memory is not enough, just create a swap memory or upgrade your RAM.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I already tried that and nothing ...

Comment: try higher memory, example 32GB or more

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to start the tinker with the following command.

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 artisan tinker
```

Comment: No, the error persists even if I modify my memory limit in php ... won't there be something else to do from the laravel system other than that? I already checked the drivers and others ... and nothing ..

Comment: I don't think, you need to modify the Laravel.

Comment: What do you think I should modify?

Comment: I hope It's something to do with the PHP memory limit or database memory limit.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading the whole table from the database, considering chunking the result.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#chunking-results

```
Flight::chunk(200, function ($flights) {
    foreach ($flights as $flight) {
        //
    }
});
```