# SQLSTATE[HY001] Unable to allocate sufficient memory in Larave 7.4

Tags: php, laravel, database

I try to connect MS SQL remote external database. But I got this error. I am stuck with this error, Do I miss something, how to fix this error?

> "message": "SQLSTATE[HY001] Unable to allocate sufficient memory (http://insharp.database.windows.net/:1433) (severity 8)",
> "exception": "Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Exception",
> "file": "/var/www/analytics/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDO/Exception.php",
> "line": 18,
> "trace": [
> *

```
'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],
```

```
DB::purge('dynamic');
        Config::set('database.connections.dynamic.driver', $request->db_type);
        Config::set('database.connections.dynamic.host', $request->host);
        Config::set('database.connections.dynamic.port', $request->port);
        Config::set('database.connections.dynamic.database', $request->db_name);
        Config::set('database.connections.dynamic.username', $request->user_name);
        Config::set('database.connections.dynamic.password', $request->password);
        DB::reconnect('dynamic');
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your system is simply out of RAM, once you checked and ensured that you have at least 1 GB of RAM, you just need to ensure you're **not** trying to insert big file/data into the DB (though, even small file in DB is bad practice).

Comment: My system has 4 GB RAM and I checked there is an enough space.

Comment: Has 4 GB of RAM in total, or has 4 GB remaining? I meant above that it should have "at least 1 GB of RAM" remaining, once that's the case, ensure your query/insert/update is not too big.

Comment: System has 1.9 GB remaining space, I think that enough, isn't It?

Comment: Normally that should be enough, see also: [Laravel - SQLSTATE\[HY001\] Unable to allocate sufficient memory - MsSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65395463/laravel-sqlstatehy001-unable-to-allocate-sufficient-memory-mssql)